# AWS SWF Flow Java Decider

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

How do we write Deciders in AWS SWF Flow Java framework.
All the examples provided talk only about Activity and Workflow.

The flow API has classes like DecisionTaskHandler but I am unable to find any example n Java using the flow framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Flow Framework implements deciders through [WorkflowWorker](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/WorkflowWorker.html) class that executes decision logic implemented by a class annotated with @Workflow. So to write a decider implement a Workflow :).

Comment: Thanks Maxim. Seeing the term Decider in all the documents had really got me confused